# Hexadecimal number on seven-segment

Tags: vhdl

I need to design a bank of four 4-bit registers whose contents are displayed on the seven-segment displays. So, basically just display 4 hexadecimal numbers on the 7-segment. The output switches on its own with every clock cycle. I'm using a Basys2 board for this. This is what I have so far...

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Register_Bank is
port( x: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        disp_en: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        z:  out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        ck,reset: in std_logic);
end Register_Bank;

architecture Behavioral of Register_Bank is

Type my_state is(s0,s1,s2,s3);
Signal n_s: my_state;
Signal ck_div: std_logic;
Signal temp,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp0,temp_main: std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
Signal R0,R1,R2,R3 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

-- 
process(temp_main)
begin
case temp_main is
    when "0000" => z <= "00000011";
    when "0001" => z <= "10011111";
    when "0010" => z <= "00100101";
    when "0011" => z <= "00001101";
    when "0100" => z <= "10011001";
    when "0101" => z <= "01001001";
    when "0110" => z <= "01000001";
    when "0111" => z <= "00011111";
    when "1000" => z <= "00000001";
    when "1001" => z <= "00001001";
    when "1010" => z <= "00010001";
    when "1011" => z <= "11000001";
    when "1100" => z <= "01100011";
    when "1101" => z <= "10000101";
    when "1110" => z <= "01100001";
    when "1111" => z <= "01110001";
    when others => null;

--temp3 <= x<3>;
--temp2 <= x<2>;
--temp1 <= x<1>;
--temp0 <= x<0>;

--wiring the register contents to outputs
temp3 <= R3;
temp2 <= R2;
temp1 <= R1;
temp0 <= R0;

--state machine for TMD
Process(x,ck_div)
begin
if ck_div ='1' and ck_div'event then
case n_s is
    when s0 => 
        temp <= x<0>; 
        disp_en <= "0111";
        n_s <= s1;
    when s1 =>
        temp <= x<1>;
        disp_en <= "1011";
        n_s <= s2;
    when s2 =>
        temp <= x<2>;
        disp_en <= "1101";
        n_s <= s3;
    when s3 =>
        temp <= x<3>;
        disp_en <= "1110";
        n_s <= s0;  
end case;
end if;
end process;

-- clock division
process(ck)
variable count: integer;
begin
if ck ='1' and ck'event then
    if reset ='1' then
        count := 0;
        ck_div <= '0';
    elsif reset ='0' then
        if count = 999999 then
            ck_div <= not ck_div;
            count := 0;
        else
            count := count + 1;
        end if; 
    end if;
end if;
end process;    

end Behavioral;
```

I know the logic is off and there are syntactical errors as well. I need help trying to debug this. I'd greatly appreciate help!

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework, optimizing the logic for 7-segment LCD is a classical practice a lot of CS students have to solve... if it is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: So, what does it not do that you expected it to?  Presumably it doesn't even compile ( temp <= x<1>; is a bit bizarre!)?  Give us a chance please, make it compile, or ask specific questions about compile problems.  Then move onto functional problems (in simulation first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you tried to submit code that is at least syntactically correct. If you run it ModelSim (or through the [Sigasi](http://www.sigasi.com) editor) you'll see two trivial syntax errors:

- Missing two "END" keywords
- Vector slices use round parentheses: `x(1)`, not diamond shaped `x<1>`

Only after fixing this, you can work on the behavior of your design.

There is some code you might want to look at here: http://www.sigasi.com/content/7-segment-display

Comment: Sorry, I know the code didn't compile and i gave up after a while. Only to find out the next day that I was missing some vital information like the use of buttons to change my inputs for the hexadecimal numbers. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't use `ck_div` as a clock.  Change you code so that it goes high for one tick in 1000000.  Then change the main process to use that signal as an *enable*:

```
if rising_edge(clk) and ck_div = '1' then
```

This keeps your design fully synchronous to one clock which means the tools find life much easier - and anything you can do to make the tools life easier is a win for the designer.

Comment: Sorry, I know the code didn't compile and i gave up after a while. Only to find out the next day that I was missing some vital information like the use of buttons to change my inputs for the hexadecimal numbers. Thanks for your reply!